# LTspice TABLE keyword confusing

Tags: ltspice, subcircuit

My need is to model the optocoupler SFH615A-2. I googled with the words: "SFH615A-2 spice model" then it leds me to Mouser's site: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-Semiconductors/SFH615A-2?qs=xCMk%252BIHWTZOVkAxZ%2FTy4%252BQ%3D%3D
At the nearly end of this page, I mentioned the line "SPICE Model BJT 10 mA" and I downloaded it. This contains a zip file, I extracted it and got the following code lines:

---

```
.SUBCKT BJT_10mA A K C E PARAMS: REL_CTR=1
D1 A D DIRED    ;IRED
Vsense D K 0 ;IF Current sense
Hd R 0 Vsense 1 ;I-V
Rd R T 10K
Cd T 0 0.2n
Rdummy B 0 4G
Q1 C B E [E] QBJT ;phototransistor
* V-I
Gpcg C B TABLE  ;Photodetector {(IC vs IF) / Q1 BF}
+ {0.34*REL_CTR*(V(T)**1.658*exp(limit(4.3-60*V(T),-50,50))*
+ ((4*10**(-9)*(REL_CTR**6))-(7*10**(-7)*(REL_CTR**5))+(5*10**(-5)*(REL_CTR**4))-(0.0015*(REL_CTR**3))+
+ (0.023*(REL_CTR**2))-(0.155*(REL_CTR))+2.2261)/100)}
+ (0,0) (10,10)
.model DIRED D IS=1P N=1.948621 BV=6 IBV=10U
+ CJO=18.8P EG=1.424 TT=500N
.model QBJT NPN IS=3.64P BF=100 NF=1.193293 BR=10 TF=13N TR=350n
+ CJE=5.16P CJC=18P VAF=65 ISS=0 CJS=7.74p
.ends
```

---

My question is at the current source define `Gpcg C B TABLE {0.34*REL_CTR*(V(T)**1.658*exp(... }`

What exactly this "TABLE" means?
I read the LTspice help file and got that the TABLE function has only one syntax:
Syntax: Gxxx n+ n- nc+ nc- table=(, , ...)

Comment: This syntax is strange because first, it’s not documented in LTspice since it’s Pspice syntax but LTspice has hidden PSpice compatibility. Second, it’s additionally weird because it’s missing the equals sign that’s normally supposed to be there. Check out page 134 of this PDF. https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jan/spice/PSpice_ReferenceguideOrCAD.pdf

Comment: @SteKulov Your comment is good enough to be an answer.

Comment: @qrk Uggghhh.....but I'm lazy.  FINE....I'll do it.

Comment: @qrk  For the record, there was an answer already posted when I commented...but it seems to have been removed since....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax used in your subcircuit is strange for two reasons.  First, it's not documented in LTspice because it's PSpice syntax and LTspice includes hidden PSpice compatibility behind the scenes.  Second, it doesn't follow the exact PSpice syntax because there is normally an "equals sign" between the evaluated expression and the table data.  If you check out [page 134 of the PSpice Reference Guide](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ejan/spice/PSpice_ReferenceguideOrCAD.pdf) you can see the "official" syntax (duplicated below; E and G sources use the same syntax).

[image]

LTspice is able to see the closing brace `}` around the end of the expression and ignore that the `=` is missing after it, allowing your subcircuit to run without issue.